# The largest Triceratops specimen

Tags: palaeontology, dinosaurs, fossil

Almost every dinosaur book writes that Triceratops maximal length was about 9 meters (29.5-30 ft), see for example Thomas R. Holtz's [dinosaur genus list 2011](https://www.geol.umd.edu/%7Etholtz/dinoappendix/appendix.html). My question is what specimen is the base or indication for that estimate, and what is its size? It could be a partial skeleton or maybe just a gigantic skull, and not a full vertebral-column specimen.
Also, what is the largest complete (or almost complete) skeleton of Triceratops? Peter Dodson in "The Horned dinosaurs" (1996) notes a 7.9 meters long skeleton at Minnesota's Nature Museum, but since then new almost complete skeletons have been found. If it is on display, please write in which museum it can be seen.

**Added in edit:**
The following [image of EoFauna on DeviantArt](https://www.deviantart.com/eofauna/art/Eotriceratops-vs-Triceratops-341153326) and the discussion that follows suggests that Triceratops was as big as *Eotriceratops*, reaching a length of 9 meters and a mass of about 10 tonnes (10,000 kg) with skull about 2.7 meters long.

**Added in edit 2021 December:**
A specimen named "[Big John](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_John_(dinosaur))" is 8 meters long and according to reports it is the largest mounted skeleton of *Triceratops*. It has 262 cm long skull and 1 meter long brow horns.

Comment: There's some references here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torosaurus. quote:  in 2006 Andrew Farke had pointed out that the new skulls described by him were on average even longer than Hatcher's original two: MOR 1122 has a length of 252 centimetres and MOR 981 of 277 centimetres.

Comment: here's a pic https://pbs.twimg.com/media/D6PV2vMVUAAVAmR.jpg